# springboot elasticsearch date convert ConversionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

1. springboot version:2.5.2
2. elasticsearch version:7.3.0
3. elasticsearch-client: rest-hight-level
4. the entity

```
    @Id
    public String id;
    public long uid;
    public long tid;
    public int type;
    public int recordType;
    public int code;
    public double cost;
    public double costNonpay;
    public int costType;
    public String remark;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z")
    public Date time;
```

5. error
   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ConversionException: Unable to parse date value '2021-02-21T14:19:27+08:00' of property 'Trade.time' with configured converters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date time string you have represent with [offset](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-java-8-date-time-api-offsetdatetime-parse.html) you can use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to parse the string with custom pattern

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")
public Date time;
```